# Why is decomposition failing me here

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, factoring

Why is decomposition failing me here, and what can I do about it in the future

$$8x^2+10x+3 = 8x^2-2x+12x+3 = -2x(-4x+1)+3(4x+1) $$

see how one $4x$ is negative? That's what I mean by failing

Comment: The right side is wrong. The first term it yields is $8x^2$. Look at it again.

Comment: $8x-2x \not = -2x(-4x+1)$ unless $x=1$.  What are you trying to do? Are you missing some squares?

Comment: My guess is that the first term should be $8x^2$.

Comment: factor it but thanks

Comment: what would be the easiest way to factor this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$8x^2+10x+3 = (8x^2 + 4x) + (6x + 3) = 4x(2x+1)+3(2x+1)=(4x+3)(2x+1)$